# Java how to refresh sql outcome in jlist

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlist

I'm having a little problem with my Java application. I want to show the orders of a restaurant in my left Jlist, and the details of a selected order in the right Jlist. The orders get read in through a MySQL query and then printed into the Jlist. However, we want to make a refresh button with whitch the query has to be executed again and then printed to the Jlist. However, I can not make the refresh button work. It does refresh the content, but it opens a new Jfram window...

from the GUI Class:

```
public class Barscherm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private BedieningsManager manager;
/**
 * Creates new form Barscherm
 */
public Barscherm() {
    manager = new BedieningsManager();
    initComponents();
}

    private void opvraagKnopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       // This is the refresh button                                     

    jPanel1.removeAll();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Barscherm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

From the manager Class:

```
public class BedieningsManager {
private ArrayList<Barbestelling> bestellingen;
private int tafelNummer,bestelNummer, aantal;
Database db1 = new Database();

public BedieningsManager(){
    this.bestellingen = new ArrayList<Barbestelling>();
    maakBestellingen();
   public void maakBestellingen(){
    aantal = db1.getAantalRijenBarBestelling();
    Barbestelling[] bss = new Barbestelling[aantal];
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++){

        tafelNummer = db1.getTafelnummer(i);
        bestelNummer = db1.getBestelNummer(i);
        bss[i] = new Barbestelling(bestelNummer,tafelNummer,"Geplaatst");
        bestellingen.add(bss[i]);

    }

}
public ArrayList<String> toonBarbestellingen()
{
    ArrayList<String> tafelNummers = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Barbestelling i : bestellingen)
    {
        tafelNummers.add(i.getTafelNummer());
    }

    return tafelNummers;
}

public ArrayList<Barbestelling> getBestellingen()
{
    return bestellingen;
}

public String getDetails(String barbestelling){
    String details = "";
    boolean found = false;
    int count = 0;

    while(!found && count < bestellingen.size())
    {
        if(bestellingen.get(count).getTafelNummer().equals(barbestelling))
        {
            found = true;
            details = bestellingen.get(count).getDetails();
        }
        else
        {
            count ++;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        System.out.println("Bestelling met Tafelnummer: " + barbestelling + " bestaat niet!");
    }


    return details;
}
}
```

the database query's:

```
public class Database {
private Connection con;
private int bestelNummer;


public Database() {



    String connectiestring;

    connectiestring = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hartigehap";
    try {   

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectiestring,"root", "");  

    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Melding: " + e.getMessage());
    }             
}
public int getAantalRijenBestelRegel(int bestelNummer){
      Statement stmt;
      ResultSet rs;
      String query;
      int i = 0;


      try {
          stmt = con.createStatement();
          query = "SELECT COUNT(ItemItemID) FROM bestelregel WHERE barbestellingbestellingnummer = '"+bestelNummer+"'";
          rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
          while (rs.next()){
            i = rs.getInt("COUNT(ItemItemID)");
          }


      }
      catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Melding1: " + e.getMessage());
      } 

      return i ;
}
   public int getAantalRijenBarBestelling(){
      Statement stmt;
      ResultSet rs;
      String query;
      int i = 0;


      try {
          stmt = con.createStatement();
          query = "SELECT BestellingNummer FROM barbestelling WHERE Status = 'Geplaatst'";
          rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while ( rs.next() ) {
                i++;
            }
          stmt.close();
      }  
      catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Melding1: " + e.getMessage());
      } 

      return i ;
}

public String getProduct(int bestelNummer){

  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;
  String query;
  String productNaam = "";

  try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    query = "SELECT Naam FROM item, bestelregel WHERE bestelregel.barbestellingbestellingnummer = "+bestelNummer+" AND item.ItemID = bestelregel.ItemItemID";
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


    rs.absolute(bestelNummer);
          productNaam = rs.getString("Naam");  

  }
  catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Melding1: " + e.getMessage());
  } 
   return productNaam;
}    

public int getTafelnummer(int bestelNummer){

  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;
  String query;
  int tafelNummer = 0;
  bestelNummer++;

  try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    query = "SELECT barbestelling.TafelNummer FROM barbestelling WHERE barbestelling.BestellingNummer = "+bestelNummer+"";
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


    rs.absolute(1);
          tafelNummer = rs.getInt("Tafelnummer");  

  }
  catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Melding1: " + e.getMessage());
  } 
   return tafelNummer;
}    
public int getAantal(int bestelNummer){

  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;
  String query;
  int aantal = 0;

  try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    query = "SELECT Aantal FROM bestelregel WHERE barbestellingbestellingnummer = '"+bestelNummer+"'";
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


    rs.absolute(bestelNummer);
          aantal = rs.getInt("Aantal");  


  }
  catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Melding1: " + e.getMessage());
  } 
   return aantal;
}    
 public String getBestelRegel(int bestelNummer) {

      Statement stmt;
      ResultSet rs;
      String query, querytekst1;
      String details = "";

      try {
          stmt = con.createStatement();
          query = "SELECT bestelregel.Aantal, item.Naam FROM bestelregel, item WHERE bestelregel.barbestellingbestellingnummer = " + bestelNummer + " AND item.ItemID = bestelregel.ItemItemID";
          rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


          while(rs.next()){

                  String aantal = rs.getString("Aantal");
                  String naam = rs.getString("Naam");
                  details += aantal + " " + naam + "\n";

          }

        }

      catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Melding1: " + e.getMessage());
      }
      return details;
  }

public int getBestelNummer(int bestelNummer) {

  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;
  String query;
  bestelNummer++;

  try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    query = "SELECT BestellingNummer FROM barbestelling WHERE BestellingNummer = '"+bestelNummer+"'  AND Status = 'Geplaatst'";
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


    rs.absolute(1);
          bestelNummer = rs.getInt("BestellingNummer");  


  }
  catch(Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Melding1: " + e.getMessage());
  } 
   return bestelNummer;
}

 private boolean sluitConnectie() {       

  boolean x = false;  
  try {
    if(con != null) {
      con.close();
      x = true;          
    }
  } catch(SQLException e) {
      x = false;
    }        
  return x;
}

}
```

A screenshot of the GUI:

http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/1676/schoolopdrachtgui.jpg

Comment: Whew the code from the refresh button or database query?

Comment: the refresh button is called "opvraagKnop" (we have to program with dutch names) and the query simple selects the products of all the orders that still have to be delivered.

Comment: i added the query's, but don't mind the mess. we had to do it this way, as the DB we got was kinda screwed up...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [JList.setMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setModel%28javax.swing.ListModel%29)l to set your own instance of the [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html). It has methods for adding, changing and removing the content, and also JList should monitor it observing your changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but i'm pretty new to Java. So do you mind explaining it a little?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your actionPerformed method

```
private void opvraagKnopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       // This is the refresh button                                     
    jPanel1.removeAll();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Barscherm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

First, you remove all the active component from `jPanel1`, then you create a new `Barsdherm` window and make it visible.

What should be happening is you should be loading all the values from the database that you need and refreshing the list model.

There's not enough code in your example to be 100% sure of an exact solution, but one method would be to load all the values from the database you need into a new `DefaultListModel` and apply this model to your `JList`

Take a look at [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for examples

Comment: Would you like more code to get what's being done? Because the only extra code i have, is the code from the GUI. The rest is all there

Comment: Here's the thing. You've obviously loaded the data from the database once. What you need to do is simply replicate the process within the actionPerformed method